# Why does the TCP handling mechanism in the OS wait for an ACK from client before sending

Tags: tcp

Im observing the below behavor in a TCP connection between a server application and a client which run on two different red hat machines.

**Example 1**

1. Client acks everything until now (ACK with WND = 1424)
2. Server sends 296 bytes to TCP layer and it is sent to the client(PUSH/ACK)
3. Server sends 296 bytes to TCP layer and it is sent to the client(PUSH/ACK)
4. Server sends 296 bytes to TCP layer and it is sent to the client(PUSH/ACK)
5. Server sends/tries to send 239 bytes to TCP layer but: either one of the following two happens

   1. the OS waits ~30ms until ACK from client is received before sending these bytes (this x bytes send will be referred as delayed message below)
   2. the tcp send call returns EWOULDBLOUCK or EAGAIN (I think this is not possible because 239+239+239+239 < 1424. Please correct me if I'm wrong

**Example 2**

1. Client acks everything until now (ACK with WND=1424)
2. Server sends 239 bytes to TCP layer and it is sent to the client
3. Server sends/tries to send 239 bytes to TCP layer and one of the two things in the above happens

The problem I want to understand is why the server application or the OS waits until the ACK when window size for the client is big enough? Is this something I can tune in the OS level. Can I force server to send all bytes until the window of the client is filled?

As per my understanding there are two possible reasons

1. Server application does not pass the 'delayed message' to TCP level becuase the send system call returned EWOULDBLOUCK or EAGAIN.
2. Application does pass the message to TCP layer, but the operating system does not send it until an ACK from the client is received.

In all the delayed message scenarios, there is an ACK from the client before the SEND of the delayed message. Also the working logic of the application suggests that it does pass the message to the TCP layer.

Can you please suggest where I should focus on the troubleshooting of this.

1. Is it some OS level setting I can set in either the client or server side
2. Is this somehow a fault in the application server?
3. Am I wrong in assuming OS doesn't return EWOULDBLOCK until messages fill up the window

Comment: This looks like a very interesting question but it's hard to know what to suggest without specific evidence.  May I assume that "window" refers to the window described under  "Flow Control" in [RFC 793](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc793) page 4?  Of your two possible reasons I would investigate 1 first.  Specifically see if you can get precise timings of when *data is sent*, when *ACK is received* **compared to** when *a blocking call to [send()](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/sendto.2.html) starts and and returns*.

Comment: By window I mean the Win= value shown in Wireshark.

Comment: Sounds like the same thing. The two ideas I have to are: 1) The app is being delayed because `send()` has not returned. 2) The "window" in the previous ACK is smaller than both the [MTU](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximum_transmission_unit) and smaller than the data waiting in the outgoing TCP buffer, meaning the sender believes it can reduce the number of packets required if it waits for another ACK.  I've never read [Nagle's algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nagle%27s_algorithm) but it might be worth reading [RFC 896](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc896)

Comment: Turning off Nagle's algorithm https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17842406/how-would-one-disable-nagles-algorithm-in-linux

Comment: I have already turned it off.. @PhilipCouling

Comment: So now my question is: Is it okay for sender side TCP mechanism to wait for the client ack when Nagel's is off (tcp_no_delay = 1) and there is data to be sent in the buffer?

Comment: TCP simply cannot send anything from a new window until everything from the current window has been acknowledged. That behavior is so that it can discard the current window buffer, but it cannot do that until everything in the current window has been acknowledged. That is simply the way TCP works.

Comment: It appears that PasanW has been trying to find a good home for this question. U&L is likely that place, given the Red Hat OS involved.

Comment: I'll note for any answerers at U&L their [post on Network Engineering](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/62844/why-is-a-packet-is-not-sent-until-ack-is-received-when-window-size-is-sufficient) which has an Answer, as well as their follow-up posts to Server Fault [one](https://serverfault.com/questions/986824/why-is-a-packet-is-not-sent-by-tcp-until-ack-is-received-when-window-size-is-suf) and [two](https://serverfault.com/questions/986867/why-does-the-tcp-server-wait-for-an-ack-when-sufficient-window-is-available-at-c)

Comment: PasanW, it would be kind to continue enhancing your question with what you've learned from your previous posts (as well as your OS, thank you!), so that answerers here don't have to retrace all those steps with you.

Comment: It appears your NE post was migrated [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/545725/why-is-a-packet-is-not-sent-until-ack-is-received-when-window-size-is-sufficient); I will close this post as a duplicate of that one so that answers can all be in the same place.